# Finding the max of a column of a 2d array and save it into a 1d array

Tags: java, arrays

okay so I have a 10x10 2d Array and I found out how to calculate the minimum and maximum value of the column. I want to save the minimum values into on 1d array and the maximum values into a separate 1d array. I found out how to do this, but my 1d arrays just print out a bunch of 0s that equal the value so like 16 0s instead of just the number.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class F {

public static void main (String args []) throws Exception
{
            File a = new File("C:\\users\\James\\desktop\\A10Array.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(a);
    int[][] arr = new int [10][10];

        for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
            for (int j=0;j<10;j++)
                arr[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<10;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(arr[i][j] +"\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        } System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int minInCol = arr[0][i];
            int maxInCol = arr[0][i];
            double sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                sum+=arr[j][i];
                if (minInCol > arr[j][i]) {
                    minInCol = arr[j][i];
                }

                if (maxInCol < arr[j][i]) {
                    maxInCol = arr[j][i];
                }

            }
            int[]min = new int [minInCol];
            int[]max = new int [maxInCol];
                System.out.print(Arrays.toString(max));

        }


scan.close();   
}
}
```

Comment: What do you think 'new int [minInCol];' do?

Comment: You should be allocating the arrays min and max outside the for loop and saving minInCol and maxInCol in array min and max, as min[i] = minInCol, max[i]=maxInCol. min and max array should have size equal to number of columns in 2d array

Answer (score 0):

```
int[]min = new int [minInCol];
int[]max = new int [maxInCol];
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(max));
```

You just create the arrays with the length is the min and max value, but you don't init the array. So by default the out put for empty array is 0